# Check if every item in a struct is unchanged

Tags: go, struct, comparison

I have the following package:

```
// Contains state read in from the command line
type State struct {
    Domain          string  // Domain to check for
    DomainList      string  // File location for a list of domains
    OutputNormal    string  // File to output in normal format
    OutputDomains   string  // File to output domains only to
    Verbose         bool    // Verbose prints, incl. Debug information
    Threads         int     // Number of threads to use
    NoColour        bool    // Strip colour from output
    Silent          bool    // Output domains only
    Usage           bool    // Print usage information
}

func InitState() (state State) {
    return State { "", "", "", "", false, 20, false, false, false }
}

func ValidateState(s *State) (result bool, error string ) {
    if s.Domain == "" && s.DomainList == "" {
        return false, "You must specify either a domain or list of domains to test"
    }

    return true, ""
}
```

Within `ValidateState()` I would like to return true if every item in `State` is the same as what is defined in `InitState()`. I can see a few ways to do this, but nothing that seems concise. I would greatly value some direction!

Comment: In any case, please show your best attempt, and explain how you want to see it improved. This type of question might be better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Struct values are comparable if all their fields are comparable (see [Spec: Comparison operators](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators)). And since in your case this holds, we can take advantage of this.

In your case the simplest and most efficient way to achieve this is to save a struct value holding the initial value, and whenever you want to tell if a struct value (if any of its fields) has changed, simply compare it to the saved, initial value. This is all it takes:

```
var defaultState = InitState()

func isUnchanged(s State) bool {
    return s == defaultState
}
```

Testing it:

```
s := InitState()
fmt.Println(isUnchanged(s))

s.Threads = 1
fmt.Println(isUnchanged(s))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/fZxxdq4Lyiu)):

```
true
false
```

Note that this solution will still work without any modification if you change the `State` type by adding / removing / renaming / rearranging fields as long as they all will still be comparable. As a counter example, if you add a field of slice type, it won't work anymore as slices are not comparable. It will result in a compile-time error. To handle such cases, [`reflect.DeepEqual()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#DeepEqual) might be used instead of the simple `==` comparison operator.

Also note that you should create default values of `State` like this:

```
func NewState() State {
    return State{Threads: 20}
}
```

You don't have to list fields whose values are the zero values of their types.

Comment: Great answer! Definitely cleaner than my solution (given all fields are comparable).

Comment: @EmilePels If there are uncomparable fields, comparing with `reflect.DeepEqual()` is still simpler, "safer" and more universal.